# Is there a difference between children[0] and firstElementChild?

Tags: javascript, dom

[ParentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode) interface declares property [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild). I have seen people using [children](http://Is%20there%20a%20difference%20between%20using%20%60firstElementChild%60%20and%20%60children[0]%60?)[0] everywhere, so it makes me wonder, is there a difference between using `firstElementChild` and `children[0]`?

Comment: Different levels of browser support, since IE8 had `.children`, though buggy, and IE9 was the first IE to get `.firstElementChild`. Also, the value returned when there's no first element will be `null` with `.firstElementChild` and `undefined` with `.children[0]`.

Comment: I don't see it listed in caniuse, https://caniuse.com/#search=firstElementChild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`children[0]` will produce the same result as `firstElementChild`. Will firstElementChild returns the first child node as an element node (ignores text and comment nodes). The `children` property is fully supported in IE6 to IE8. However, in these versions, it returns element nodes AND comment nodes. IE9+ returns only element nodes.

Source: [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp)

Keep rocking!